# How to add a line at a specific line row to a file's content using node.js and Promises

Tags: node.js, promise, fs

Situation: I made some code that loops through a main directory and its subdirectories looking for htm files, once it finds the .htm file it is supposed to add a line after the head tag, then it should loop further looking for all other .htm files in the main directory and perfmoring the same action.

The code:

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var mainDirectory = 'directory';

function addLineInFile() { //execute the steps needed to alter the file's content in sequential order.
  readContent() //can be found below.
    .then(lookForHead) //can be found below.
    .then(writeNewContent) //can be found below.
}
addLineInFile();

function readContent() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    FileContent = [];
    fs.readFile(extendedDirectoryPath, (err, data) => {
      fileContent = data.toString('utf8').split("\n");
      console.log("Read file content")
    });
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(FileContent);
    }
  });
}

function lookForHead(FileContent) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var string = "<head>"
    for (i = 0; i < FileContent.length; i++) {
      console.log("Looking for <head>.")
      if (FileContent[i].indexOf(string) !== -1) {
        console.log("found <head>")
        FileContent.splice(i + 1, 0, 'line to be added')
      }
    }
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(FileContent);
    }
  });
}

function writeNewContent(FileContent) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("Started Writing to the file!")
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(extendedDirectoryPath);
    file.on('error', function(err) { /* error handling */ });
    FileContent.forEach(function(v) {
      file.write(v.join(', ') + '\n');
      console.log("Wrote a line to the file.")
    });
    file.end();
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    } else {
      resolve(FileContent);
    }
  });
}
```

Problem: The file is written to **BEFORE** the content that has to be written to it is ready (Take a look at the output). So the writeNewContent() is executed before the readContent() and lookForHead() are done with giving it its content to be written in the file. I've tried so many different things before this like callback functions and was convinced Promises would be my solution but perhaps I'm using them incorrectly? Please keep in mind that I don't know all that much about node.js and Promises most of my work is just copy pasting from internet and changing small parts of it to my liking.

Output:

```
Got file info successfully!
file1.htm This is an htm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Got file info successfully!
file2.htm This is an htm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Got file info successfully!
file3.htm This is an htm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Got file info successfully!
file4.htm This is an htm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Got file info successfully!
someInnerDirectory is a innerDirectory
Delving deeper!
Got file info successfully!
file5.htm This is anhtm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Got file info successfully!
file6.htm This is an htm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Got file info successfully!
file7.htm This is an htm file!
Started Writing to the file!
Read file content
Read file content
Read file content
Read file content
Read file content
Read file content
Read file content
```

Comment: The first step to fix this crazy indentation is to not do everything in 1 really big block of code, but to create small functions that do a little bit. This will help _so much_ and also makes it more appealing for others to try and fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Evert for the feedback I will edit my question.

Comment: The `readline` package is useful for *streaming* a file line by line (instead of reading the whole file into memory). But that's not what you are interested in, you want to collect all lines into an array anyway. So use `fs.readFile` and then `split("\n")` it to an array, then resolve your promise. Promises don't work with streaming multiple values as well.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, so does that mean my way of writing onto the file also has to be changed?

Comment: @Refflected That looks mostly fine by idea, though there are many little mistakes. (`fileContent` vs `FileContent`, it should not be a global variable but rather be passed by argument, `lookForHead` does not need a promise at all but can synchronously `return` its result, `i` is implicitly global, `writeNewContent` should resolve its promise when the stream is finished)

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback @Bergi. Could you perhaps make a version for me with those little mistakes fixed, I'm too inexperienced in node.js to be able to see what i'm doing wrong this is mostly copy paste from other stackoverflow questions and try to make them work for my case. If I had a corrected version I can see what i'm doing wrong and learn from it :). If it's not too much trouble ofcourse, don't feel obligated.

Answer (score 0):

Well done on your work so far and sticking with it. Good to see you are using recursion too. You are creating a function called addLineInFile but not executing it. [I did something similar a while back, check it out](https://github.com/roppa/read-directory/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Unfortnuately my steps aren't happening sequentially though do you perhaps have an idea to solve this? I edited my question if u want more information all should be available in there.